# Find 'connected components' in graph

Tags: java, hashmap, graph-traversal

I'm building a thesaurus using a `HashMap <String,ArrayList<String>>` to hold words and their synonyms (this data structure is required).

For the purpose of the assignment, the synonymity relation is considered transitive. (We can imagine the thesaurus as a graph).
What I'm trying to accomplish is to print this graph in a text file, with a connected component on each line. In other words, all the words that can be pooled together as synonyms should go on a single line.

```
public void save() {
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(defaultDefinitionFile);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        Set<String> keys = thesaurus.keySet();
        Iterator<String> ite = keys.iterator();
        while (ite.hasNext()) {
            String key = ite.next();
            out.write(key);
            ArrayList<String> synonyms = thesaurus.get(key);
            Iterator<String> i = synonyms.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                String syn = i.next();
                out.write(","+syn);
                keys.remove(syn);
            }
            out.write("\r\n");
        }
        out.close();
        fw.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error writing to file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is how I pictured it to happen:

Print a word along with each of its synonyms, then remove those synonyms from the data structure so we don't have duplicate lines.

Problem is of course that I can't delete anything while i'm iterating over the content of the hashmap.

Any alternative approaches I'm missing?

P.S. I'm keeping the 'graph' metaphor throughout only because i needed the title to be eloquent and succint. I understand that this metaphor is limited in usefulness.

Comment: this problem suited for map reduce (can't find a good reference for it right now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the words that were printed in a [Set](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), and then only handle words that are not yet in the set.

*Side remark*: though it's true that one can think about this as a graph problem, your code doesn't treat this as such. If we were to treat this as a graph problem, then we wouldn't make the assumption that each word has all its synonyms listed in the corresponding `ArrayList`, thus calling for the calculation of the symmetric and transitive closure. Only then would we extract the equivalence classes.

(In reality the synonym relation is not transitive, I know.)

Comment: I understand the distinction. You're right, the model of the thesaurus represents only one kind of graph, one in which each connected component is a complete graph.

Answer (score 0):

I don't this this (your general idea) will work as "synonimity" is not a transitive property.

There are plenty of words that have synonyms that are not themselves synonyms.

Comment: Being a homework assignment, this is part of the requirement, as to keep things simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the item, add it to a list of items to ignore.